# SockJS & Stomp closes connection immediate after create

Tags: angular, websocket, spring-cloud, stomp, sockjs

I'm trying to establish WebSocket between Angular and Spring Cloud. It connects, but closes connection immediately after creation, what can be wrong?

Angular dependencies:

```
"sockjs-client": "^1.1.4",
"stompjs": "^2.3.3",
```

Spring WebSocket configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        // prefix for subscribe
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        // prefix for send
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
}
```

And CORSFilter to work with origins:

```
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

        // This is to be replaced with a list of domains allowed to access the server
        //You can include more than one origin here
        private final List<String> allowedOrigins = Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000");

        public void destroy() {

        }

        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            // Lets make sure that we are working with HTTP (that is, against HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse objects)
            if (req instanceof HttpServletRequest && res instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
                HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
                HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

                // Access-Control-Allow-Origin
                String origin = request.getHeader("Origin");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", allowedOrigins.contains(origin) ? origin : "");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            }

            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }

        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        }
    }
```

Adding to http:

`http.addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class)`;

Angular code:

```
Stomp.over(new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/gs-guide-websocket')).connect({}, () => {
            console.log('TEST');
        }, () => {
            console.log('FAILS');
        });
```

And Stacktrace:

```
stomp.js:134 Opening Web Socket...
core.es5.js:2925 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
stomp.js:134 Web Socket Opened...
stomp.js:134 >>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000


stomp.js:134 Whoops! Lost connection to http://localhost:8080/gs-guide-websocket
app.component.ts:50 FAILS
```

Thanks

Comment: How is this related to spring cloud?

Comment: @spencergibb Im setting up it on spring cloud, just mentioned it, maybe it's related

Comment: Found the issue, it couldn't resolve route id and threw an exception without single message into logs.

Comment: I still don't see spring cloud anywhere

Comment: Do you mean Spring Boot?

Comment: It's my mistake, I didn't mention any information about this. I use Spring Cloud Netflix and there were some troubles with Zuul proxy.

Comment: Zuul does not support web sockets

Answer (score 0):

Add `setAllowedOrigins("*")`

replace `registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();`

with  `registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();`